# Setting autocomplete to a value other than off in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, input, autocomplete, autofill

In order to remove address auto-completion in Chrome, Google says you need to set 'autocomplete' to some unexpected text. So not off or false.

However when I try to do this with javascript, using either:

```
addressInput.setAttribute("autocomplete", "nope");
//or
addressInput.autocomplete = "nope";
```

It still sets autocomplete to off. I am just wondering if anyone has a chrome **javascript** solution where I can set an attribute on an input field to nope.

Comment: It appears to work via console. However not by scripts.

Comment: I do not imagine a scenario in which you require this implementation, autocomplete is well documented in mdn please check this publication https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion or this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete. But if you really need to place an attribute the nope value you could use data attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Unfortunately since August 2019, if you have an input box on chrome where the name or id attribute contains the word address. Chrome ignores autocomplete when its set to off. It is then recommended to set it to something unrecognised or random, such as nope.

Comment: Whats adding the extra complexity, is I need to change it via javascript via a chrome extension. So I am injecting a new javascript script onto the page, however instead of setting autocomplete to nope. It's setting it to off.